WPF DatePicker Datagrid Filter
I want to filter the data in my datagrid by date. The start and end date will be entered and the data between those dates will be returned.
The data type in which I keep the date in my database is DateTime;
2024-09-09 19:32:50.160
like this.

This is my datagrid. I'm working on a parking lot project. The left one DatePicker is startDate and the other one is endDate
My XAML Code;
<Grid Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="4" Margin="110 0 15 0" >
    <DatePicker Name="startDatePicker" SelectedDateChanged="StartDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" Width="140" Margin="20,1,140,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    <DatePicker Name="endDatePicker" SelectedDateChanged="EndDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" Width="140" Margin="165,1,-5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>

<DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}" Margin="15 20 15 0" RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}"  CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}" x:Name="carActionDataGrid" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Plaka" Binding="{Binding Plate}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Giriş Zamanı" Binding="{Binding EntryTime, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm\}}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Çıkış Zamanı" Binding="{Binding CheckoutTime, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm\}}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Araç Durumu" Binding="{Binding Status}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kullanıcı" Binding="{Binding Username}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

In my XAML Code, I format the data in the data entry before printing it and then print it.
My C# Code;
private void StartDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (endDatePicker.SelectedDate == null || endDatePicker.SelectedDate < startDatePicker.SelectedDate)
    {
        endDatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    }

    ApplyDateFilter();
}

private void EndDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplyDateFilter();
}

private void ApplyDateFilter()
{
    if (startDatePicker.SelectedDate == null || endDatePicker.SelectedDate == null)
        return;

    var startDate = startDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date; 
    var endDate = endDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1); 

    using (var context = new BarcodeReaderEntities())
    {
        var filteredData = context.QRInfoes
            .Where(car =>
                car.EntryTime >= startDate &&
                (car.CheckoutTime == null || car.CheckoutTime <= endDate)  // CheckoutTime might be null
            )
            .ToList();

        carActionDataGrid.ItemsSource = filteredData;
    }
}

I want to filter the data in my datagrid by date. The start and end date will be entered and the data between those dates will be returned. This code is doesn't work i don't understand. I wrote a few more codes similar to this, but I don't think the problem is in the query, maybe it could be in the data type in my database, I couldn't understand it. Can you guys help me?

"The code is not working" is not very specific. Can you please [edit] your question to let us know what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it?

@KlausGütter sorry, my main language is not english. I think it's quite understandable.
I want to filter the data in my datagrid by date. The start and end date will be entered and the data between those dates will be returned.

Great, that tells us what you expect to happen, now can you tell us what does happen, and what you've done to try and debug it?

Your code and explanation are not enough for a precise answer.
For example, there is no indication of what collection, with what type of elements you pass (bind) to carActionDataGrid.ItemsSource when starting the application.
Therefore, the answer will be partially based on guesses.
I will assume that ItemsSource receives a collection with the element type Car.
        private void ApplyDateFilter()
        {
            if (startDatePicker.SelectedDate == null || endDatePicker.SelectedDate == null)
                return;

            DateTime startDate = startDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
            DateTime endDate = endDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);

            carActionDataGrid.Items.Filter = item =>
            {
                Car car = (Car) item;

                return car.EntryTime >= startDate && (car.CheckoutTime == null || car.CheckoutTime <= endDate); 
            };

        }

